# kernel is spewing ata link up messages every second

Tags: kernel, power-management, powertop

These messages are appended every 1 second:

```
ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
ata3.00: configured for UDMA/33
```

I think it may be related to me letting powertop change a power setting from whatever it was before to auto.

How can I tell the kernel to stop enabling this link? Or how do I tell it to never put ata3 to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have Aggressive Link Power Management enabled. This puts the SATA host bus adapter into a low-power state during periods of inactivity.

The per-host policy setting is in:

```
/sys/class/scsi_host/host*/link_power_management_policy
```

so to disable ALPM for say host0, try:

```
echo max_performance | sudo tee /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy
```

..you may need to apply this to all the host devices to see if this helps.